# By tag filter on review page for Help and Improvement queue

Tags: discussion, review-queues, filtering, help-improvement

I just noticed that there are 'by tag' filters under the Help and Improvement queue.  However, the tags that are visible for me are 'java' and 'php', neither of which are in my interesting tag collection.

How are these filters chosen?

Comment: yes.  fixed the typo.

Comment: it's on a different queue, but same issue as my post. they are just the most popular tags on the site.